# Сортировка столбцов матрицы по количеству простых чисел

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Есть файл, в нём матрицей 5х5 написаны 25 чисел. Нужно заменить все единицы нулями, а потом отсортировать столбцы матрицы по количеству простых чисел. Я написала следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

/* Файл: 25 чисел(матрица 5 на 5). Заменить в матрице все цифры 1 на 0. 
Отсортировать столбцы матрицы по количеству простых чисел */

int countprimes(int matrix[]); //функция считающая простые числа в строке
const int size = 5;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int matrix[size][size];

    ifstream file("in.txt");

    // Вывод массива
    cout<<"Исходный массив"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)     {
            file >> matrix[i][j];
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    file.close();

    //Замена 1 на 0
    cout<<"Заменим единицы нулями"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)     {
            if (matrix[i][j]==1) matrix[i][j]=0;
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


//Сортировка пузырьком
 for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)  {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (countprimes(matrix[i]) < countprimes(matrix[i + 1])) {
                swap(matrix[i], matrix[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Вывод после сортировки
    cout<<"Отсортированный массив"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}



int countprimes(int matrix[]){
    int count(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (matrix[i] == 2 || matrix[i] == 3 ) count++;  //Если 2 или 3, то простое
        for (int k = 2; k<= matrix[i]/2; k++) {  
            if (matrix[i] % k == 0 || matrix[i]==0) break;  //Если кратно, останавливаем цикл, число не простое
            if (k >= matrix[i] / 2) count++;    //Если проверили все кратности и не вышли из цикла, число простое
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Вывод программы следующий:

```
Исходный массив
1 23 56 4 31
44 34 11 8 41
66 22 1 35 67
89 21 31 65 73
3 9 1 27 17

Заменим единицы нулями
0 23 56 4 31
44 34 11 8 41
66 22 0 35 67
89 21 31 65 73
3 9 0 27 17

Отсортированный массив
0 23 56 4 31
44 34 11 8 41
89 21 31 65 73
3 9 0 27 17
66 22 0 35 67
```

То есть, сортирует не столбцы, а строки. Никак не могу понять, что не так с сортировкой.

Comment: "То есть, сортирует не столбцы, а строки." - что-то я не вижу, чтобы тут было что-то отсортировано

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, последние 3 строки поменялись местами

Comment: а, вы про это... вам нужно, чтобы целиком поменялись именно столбцы? В этом случае вам нужно инвертировать массив, т.к. в ф-цию `countprimes` вы передаете именно строки, а не столбцы. Да и в `for` тоже оперируете строками. Можно также изменить код функции так, чтобы она считала относительно столбцов, но в этом случае нужно много переписать. Инвертировать, имхо, будет проще

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, не подскажите, как его инвертировать? мне в цикле for(сортировочном) i и j местами поменять, или ещё при его создании?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю проще просто инвертировать матрицу перед сортировкой столбцов и после. Это позволит не менять код в проге, а просто добавить иныерсию к существующему. Вот ф-ция инверсии:

```
void invert(int ar[][size])
{
    int nova[size][size];
    for (int i{}; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j{}; j < size; ++j) {
            nova[i][j] = ar[j][i];
        }
    }
    for (int i{}; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j{}; j < size; ++j) {
            ar[i][j] = nova[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

К тому же у вас в пузырьковой сортировке ошибка: нужно не

```
        if (countprimes(matrix[i]) < countprimes(matrix[i + 1])) {
            swap(matrix[i], matrix[i + 1]);
```

а

```
        if (countprimes(matrix[j]) < countprimes(matrix[j + 1])) {
            swap(matrix[j], matrix[j + 1]);
```

Вот ответ, который получается:

```
1 23 56 4 31 
44 34 11 8 41 
66 22 1 35 67 
89 21 31 65 73 
3 9 1 27 17 

Заменим единицы нулями
0 23 56 4 31 
44 34 11 8 41 
66 22 0 35 67 
89 21 31 65 73 
3 9 0 27 17 


2 1 2 0 5 

Отсортированный массив
4 23 0 56 31 
8 34 44 11 41 
35 22 66 0 67 
65 21 89 31 73 
27 9 3 0 17
```

Comment: функцию нужно вставить до сотритовки и после

Comment: спасибо, всё работает! я при выводе в конце i с j поменяла)

Comment: я не совсем понял: вы исправили ошибку и использовали инвертирование или просто исправили ошибку и все заработало?

Comment: я перед сортировкой инвертировала матрицу, а при выводе поменяла i и j местами

Comment: чтобы не менять местами i и j просто инвертируйте еще раз и все. Тобишь инвертирвание должно быть перед сортировкой и после - тогда все матрица приходит к изночальному виду (ну и отсортированной).